# Who is controller in Cocoa MVC document architecture?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller

I am in the process of learning Cocoa. I was going through 3 key classes that form the basis of document architecture in Cocoa.

- `NSDocument` subclass
- `NSWindowController` or its subclass
- `NSDocumentController`

I thought `NSWindowController` must be **Controller** in terms of MVC and `NSDocument` being **Model**. Any view we create in interface builder will be essentially a **View**. If it is correct then `NSWindowController` or its subclass should get the instance of `NSDocument` and it should handle all the saving, loading, updating tasks. But reading the documentation and books, it seems like `NSDocument` itself handles these tasks. Seems like model is doing a part of controller's job and I find it difficult to digest. What am I missing? Please can you clarify the conceptual model?

Comment: The controller asks the model to do these things, and the model does it however it likes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSDocument can hardly be considered a model object. It is a model controller, it owns the data model. Also, it owns window controllers, which a model object should not be doing.
A model controller should not be confused with a view controller that owns the view.
So, I would say NSDocument cannot be absolutely matched to any of those elements of the Mode-View-Controller pattern.

Comment: Yeah, maybe it’s better to think of `NSDocument` as a model controller. I don’t really have a strong opinion on it being strictly model.

Comment: I understand now. I was making a mistake by thinking `NSDocument` as a model object (in my defense, its name **does** sound like a model). It is really a **model controller** as you said.

Answer (score 1):

All three classes are controllers. Just as you have different kinds of views and different kinds of model objects, so you also have different kinds of controllers. One of the big features of MVC is that it promotes reusability, especially in the view and model classes. A big responsibility of controllers, then, is to specialize or adapt these reusable classes to the particular needs of the application. While controllers are often explained in terms of mediating between model and view, I think it's a mistake to assume that every controller interaction has to involve both model and view, or that every controller even deals with models and views directly.

Comment: Caleb, (in order to understand what you mean) could you give an example of a Controller that does not mediate between a View object and a Model object.

Comment: @BobUeland `UINavigationController` is one example of a view controller that doesn't talk to the model at all. It's been almost 4 years since I wrote this answer, but I think I was trying to say that `NSDocument` is a kind of controller even though it doesn't deal directly with views. In that sense, `NSDocument` is another example since it deals with model objects but not views.